# 'Too much' with countable noun

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

> He has too **much** friend.

Is this correct?
If so, what is rule for using **much** for countable noun or should I use **many** instead?
Please clarify.

Comment: "Friend" isn't generally used as an uncountable noun.

Comment: "Friendship" would be uncountable, for example. "too many friends" = count; "too much friendship" = non-count.

Comment: My bad ,now i have edited .

Comment: Either (1) *he has too many* ***friends*** or (2) *he is too much* ***of a friend***.

Answer (score 2):

**Much** is always used together with an uncountable noun.
**Many** is always used with nouns that are countable. ([Source](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/too-much-or-too-many-0/))

As [Friend](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/friend) is countable, **many** would be used.
(too many friends)

Comment: @Mari-LouA too many **Friends**, it's a plural noun.

Comment: Then you should make it clearer in the answer. And I would avoid capitalizing "friend" too.